# How Padding Select BootStrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, select

I do the padding but he does not show up. How can I add the padding in select?

```css
select.custom{
    padding: 30px!important;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
}
select.custom option{
    padding: 30px!important;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-12">
<select class="form-control custom">
<option>AAAAAAAAAAAAAA</option>
</select>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap selectpicker for customization the select

```css
.btn {
    padding: 20px!important;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    padding: 20px!important;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-md-12">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sel1">Select list (select one):</label>
      <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" multiple data-max-options="2">
        <option>AAAAAAAAAAAAAA</option>
      </select>
    </div>
 </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thans for help.